# Deleting Products Order history?

Tags: magento2, product, orders, admin-panel, delete

How can I Delete test order history from my Magento 2 Admin Panel?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension to delete orders from the admin panel

https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-delete-orders